# Trouble Modifying Contents of Frame Buffer

Tags: opengl

I am trying to rotate the contents of the frame buffer by putting it into a texture then putting it back into the buffer.  I get a white rotated rectangle. I suspect I am overlooking something obvious. Here is the code I am using:

```
  glReadBuffer(GL_AUX1);
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
  glCopyTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 0, 0, rect.width(),
        rect.height(), 0);
  glDrawBuffer(GL_AUX1);
  glPushMatrix();
  glRotatef(head - new_head, 0, 0, -1);
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
  glVertex2f(-1, -1);
  glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
  glVertex2f(-1, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
  glVertex2f(1, 1);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
  glVertex2f(1, -1);
  glEnd();
  glPopMatrix();
  glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

I have solved the problem.  Adding these lines to make it work:

```
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

Comment: Post your texture creation code.

Comment: glCopyTexImage2d is the texture creation code (if I am reading the man page correctly).  The AUX1 buffer is built up over a period of time using a combination vector and texture techniques.  In this segment of code I create a temporary texture in order to rotate the AUX1 buffer contents, then put them back.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a texture with glCopyTexImage2D, you only copy data to the texture, but the texture is not complete at this stage so you get a black/white texture (an indication of incomplete state).

Solution: Create a texture with:

```
glGenTextures(....)
glBindTexture(...)
glTexParameter(...) //Set MIN/MAG filter
glTexImage2D(....., NULL)
```

glTexImage2D defines the texture image, as you want to render to this texture (or copy to it), you pass NULL for the last parameteres so the texture backing store is created, but it contents are left undefined. Another suggestion is to use Framebuffer Objects (FBOs) to draw directly into a texture (without a copy)